# SourceTree Github When Pushing Large Files (MapBox Framework) Return Error

Tags: github, github-actions, atlassian-sourcetree

**Version:-1**

I wasn't able to push a commit to the repository. Below is the message and screenshot I got from Sourcetree. I am using a Mac.

Error:-

```
POST git-receive-pack (chunked)
error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 32
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date.
```

**ScreenShot**

[image: ScreenShot]

Question: Can someone please explain to me how to push.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Version:-2**

When i'm using LFS in the SourceTree.

**1. UnCommit Large Files:-**

[image: ScreenShot]

**2. Already Initialize :-**

[image: ScreenShot]

**3. Add Framework for tracked in GLS :-**

[image: ScreenShot]

i'm already using LFS in source tree. But i'm little bit confused how to use and add framework extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@GuiFalourd, @VonC. Thanks for your help. In Github LFS not tracking some files in my Repo which size more then 2MB. That's why i was faced this issue.

Here is the latest and final Github LFS file tracking list.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The `GH001: Large file detected` (seen in the screenshot) seems to indicate the connection fails because your pushed commit is too big.

As mentioned, using LFS, or filtering large object from your history ([using `git filter-repo` as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70733945/6309)), are two alternatives.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i'm already using LFS in source tree. But i'm little bit confused how to use and add framework extension. I updated my question could you please check

Comment: @Could you please help me

Comment: @RsD Having less experience in Git LFS, I will defer for now to GuiFalourd, following this page, and monitoring its resolution.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Github documentation for large files size](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github#file-size-limits):

> *GitHub limits the size of files allowed in repositories. If you attempt to add or update a file that is larger than 50 MB, you will
> receive a warning from Git. The changes will still successfully push
> to your repository, but you can consider removing the commit to
> minimize performance impact.*

Here, your file is above 100MB (according to the screenshot). In that case:

> ***GitHub blocks pushes that exceed 100 MB**.*
>
> *To track files beyond this limit, you must use Git Large File Storage (Git LFS). For more information, see "[About Git Large File
> Storage](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-git-large-file-storage)."*
>
> *If you need to distribute large files within your repository, you can create releases on GitHub.com instead of tracking the files. For more
> information, see "[Distributing large binaries](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github#distributing-large-binaries)."*

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i'm already using LFS in source tree. But i'm little bit confused how to use and add framework extension. I updated my question could you please check

Comment: @Could you please help me

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: I'm not able to push the mapBox Framework.

Comment: Could you please tell me, how to add MapBox framework with the help of Sourcetree or Commands.

Comment: Do you have any error message with some tips or stacktrace about what is happening that prevent you to push the files to the MapBox framework?

Comment: you can check my updated question. In version 1 getting error, im already tried with github large file, but im not able to add framework.

Comment: It's just that I didn't see any error on the version 2 in your question. I never used MapBox, I'm just trying to figure what is happening. When you use LFS, the files aren't store on the repository anyway, just pointers that will be used to redirect to the files (in MapBox, I guess) when someone will clone the repository.

Comment: ok i will check again and update you ASAP.

Comment: Could you please tell me, how to reset data in LFS Bandwidth.

Comment: You cannot remove or reset a bandwitch, please check here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59223469/how-to-reset-git-lfs-bandwidth